# jquery html(array) doesn't insert all items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run the javascript code below, it load specified amount of  images from Flickr.

By **var photos = photoGroup.getPhotos(10)** code, I get 10 images from cache.

Then, I can see the object has exactly 10 items by checking **console.log(photos);**

But actual image appeared on the page is less than 10 items...

I have no idea why this work this way..

Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var PhotoGroup = function(nativePhotos, callback) {
        var _cache = new Array();

        var numberOfPhotosLoaded = 0;
        var containerWidth = $("#contents").css('max-width');
        var containerHeight = $("#contents").css('max-height');

        $(nativePhotos).each(function(key, photo) {
            $("<img src='"+"http://farm" + photo["farm"] + ".staticflickr.com/" + photo["server"] + "/" + photo["id"] + "_" + photo["secret"] + "_b.jpg"+"'/>")
                .attr("alt", photo['title'])
                .attr("data-cycle-title", photo['ownername'])
                .load(function() { 
                    if(this.naturalWidth >= this.naturalHeight) {
                        $(this).attr("width", containerWidth);
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("height", containerHeight);
                    }

                    _cache.push(this);

                    if(nativePhotos.length == ++numberOfPhotosLoaded)
                        callback();
                })
        });

        var getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor((Math.random()*max)+1);
        }

        this.getPhotos = function(numberOfPhotos) {
            var photoPool = new Array();
            var maxRandomNumber = _cache.length-1;

            while(photoPool.length != numberOfPhotos) {
                var index = getRandom(maxRandomNumber);

                if($.inArray(_cache[index], photoPool)) 
                    photoPool.push(_cache[index]);
            }

            return photoPool;
        }
    }

    var Contents = function() {
        var self = this;
        var contentTypes = ["#slideShowWrapper", "#video"];

        var switchTo = function(nameOfContent) {
            $(contentTypes).each(function(contentType) {
                $(contentType).hide();
            });

            switch(nameOfContent) {
                case("EHTV") :
                    $("#video").show();
                    break;
                case("slideShow") :
                    $("#slideShowWrapper").show();
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
        }

        this.startEHTV = function() {
            switchTo("EHTV");

            document._video = document.getElementById("video");
            document._video.addEventListener("loadstart", function() {
                document._video.playbackRate = 0.3;
            }, false);
            document._video.addEventListener("ended", startSlideShow, false);
            document._video.play();
        }

        this.startSlideShow = function() {
            switchTo("slideShow");
            var photos = photoGroup.getPhotos(10)
            console.log(photos);
            $('#slideShow').html(photos);
        }

        var api_key = '6242dcd053cd0ad8d791edd975217606';
        var group_id = '2359176@N25';
        var flickerAPI = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?';
        var photoGroup;

        $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
            api_key: api_key,
            group_id: group_id,
            format: "json",
            method: "flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos",
        }).done(function(data) {
            photoGroup = new PhotoGroup(data['photos']['photo'], self.startSlideShow);
        });

    }

    var contents = new Contents();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideShow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix your method getRandom() according to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), and completely re-write method getPhotos():

```
    this.getPhotos = function(numberOfPhotos) {
        var available = _cache.length;
        if (numberOfPhotos >= available) {
            // just clone existing array
            return _cache.slice(0);
        }

        var result = [];
        var indices = [];

        while (result.length != numberOfPhotos) {
            var r = getRandom(available);
            if ($.inArray(r, indices) == -1) {
                indices.push(r);
                result.push(_cache[r]);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Check full solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/JtDzZ/

But this method still slow, because loop may be quite long to execute due to same random numbers occurred.

If you care about performance, you need to create other stable solution. For ex., randomize only first index of your images sequence.

Comment: thanks Nataliia.
Was the getRandom method occurring less items?